# Debug in VS Code a Node Typescript app running in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, traefik, vscode-debugger

I'm running a Node application in Docker, with `docker-compose`. I'm using Traefik as a proxy.
I would like to be able to debug it in VS Code but I don't manage to connect to my app:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229
```

Here are my files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:1.7
        command: --docker --docker.exposedbydefault=false
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - 9229:9229
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    core:
        image: node:alpine
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=4001
            - traefik.backend=core
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:core.localhost
        volumes:
            - ./leav_core:/app
        working_dir: /app
        command: [sh, -c, 'npm start']
        expose:
            - '9229'

volumes:
    arango_data:
        driver: local
```

The command actually executed by `npm start` is:

```
ts-node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --type-check src/`
```

The debug settings in VSCode:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
    ]
}
```

I access to my application with the URL defined on Traefik `http://core.localhost` but I don't know how to attach the debugger to it

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `expose` inside the docker-compose file should be declare like that ? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

Comment: I changed it according to the doc, but not more success

Comment: You'r writing ports: `80:80`, `9229:9229` but this is used for the expose as the left port is the exposed port and the right port is the port you wan't your redirection to point. You should try to use only ports: `9229:YourAppPort` and remove `expose`

Comment: I'm getting closer. I managed to attach the debugger to my app by exposing the 9229 right in the node container (and not the reverser proxy) and change my command to start node with inspect enabled. Now I have troubles to get my breakpoints hit, but that's another problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach was not good as there is a great tool in VS Code called "Remote development". It's an extension that allows you to attach a container directly in VS Code.

First, I had to change the way I start my node app to enable inspecting. As ts-node is not supporting the `inspect` option, you have to use this:

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 -r ts-node/register src/
```

Then, use Remote Development to get into your container.
Once you're inside, you can debug your app as you would normally do in a "classic" node environment. Personnaly, I used these settings in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 9229,
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "node_modules/**"
    ]
}
```

Everything works fine, my breakpoints are hit appropriately and can be debug my app efficiently :)